# How to upload a file to an storage bucket using an url in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want a file to be uploaded to GCP bucket.
As per my requirement I need it to be uploaded only with Bucket URL and NOT using  blob1.upload

I want to upload to the URL destination as :
`https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/IrisClassifier.sav`

when I tried using below I am getting r.status_code as 400:`f = open(filename_p)
r = requests.post(url=bucket_url, files={'file': filename_p})
print(r.status_code)`

I gave bucket_url as https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME and filename_p as IrisClassifier.sav as arguments

Answer (score 0):

The link you are pointing to at the current moment is there only to retrieve objects that are uploaded. In order to POST to it you need to do it to this one.

```
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o
```

You have more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#http-request).